# Why must I put a semicolon at the end of class declaration in C++?

Tags: c++

In a C++ class declaration:

```
class Thing
{
    ...
};
```

why must I include the semicolon?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The full syntax is, essentially,

class NAME { constituents } instances ;

where "constituents" is the sequence of class elements and methods, and "instances" is a comma-separated list of instances of the class (i.e., objects).

Example:

```
class FOO {
  int bar;
  int baz;
} waldo;
```

declares both the class FOO and an object waldo.

The instance sequence may be empty, in which case you would have just

```
class FOO {
  int bar;
  int baz;
};
```

You have to put the semicolon there so the compiler will know whether you declared any instances or not.

This is a C compatibility thing.

Comment: Doesn't even need the name or constituents: `class { } waldo;` is legal.

Comment: @MSalters Technically, "constituents" in your example is an empty sequence of class elements and methods. It's still there.

Answer (score 21):

because you can optionally declare objects

```
class Thing
{
    ...
}instanceOfThing;
```

for historical reasons

Answer (score 5):

A good rule to help you remember where to put semicolons:

- If it's a definition, it needs a semicolon at the end.  Classes, structs and unions are all information for the compiler, so need a trailing ; to mark no declared instances.
- If it contains code, it doesn't need a semicolon at the end.  If statements, for loops, while loops and functions contain code, so don't need a trailing ;.

Namespaces also don't require a trailing semicolon, because they can contain a mix of both the above (so can contain code, so don't need a semicolon).

Answer (score 5):

#### This is why...

```
int a,b,c,d;
int main(void) {
    struct y {
  }; a, b, c, d;
    struct x {
  } a, b, c, d;
}
```

Two different statements, two completely different meanings, both legal C / C++, and the only difference is the `;` after the struct declaration.

The statement `a, b, c, d;` by itself, in this context, just evaluates `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. In this context, that does nothing.

However, if it's right after the struct/class definition (before the `;`) it creates 4 instances of the created struct/class, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`

Answer (score 3):

Because it could be a definition of the next element. For example, taking it from C syntax: if you declare

`struct { 
 ...
}
main (int argc, char..`

then it assumes main returns a struct. If there was a semicolon,

`struct {
 ...
};
main (int argc, char..`

then `main` returns an int.

Comment: C++ language has no "implicit int" rule. Your second variant is simply incorrect.