# Semicolon after classes and structs

Tags: c++, syntax, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why must I put a semicolon at the end of class declaration in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783465/why-must-i-put-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-class-declaration-in-c)

**Found [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783465/why-must-i-put-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-class-declaration-in-c), vote to close please.**

Why do classes and structs have to be concluded with semicolon in C++?

Like in the following code:

```
class myClass
{



};

struct muStruct
{

};
```

This syntax isn't necessary in Java or C#. Why does the C++ parser need it?

Comment: semicolons aren't needed in the last statement of a function in Javascript. Why do Java and C# require it?

Comment: Jimmy: you can omit semicolons all over the place in JavaScript and the parser will fix it up for you. Relying on it isn't a good idea though. Even at the end of a block, omitting the semicolon may cause you maintainability problems when you start copy-and-pasting lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### This is why...

```
int a,b,c,d;
int main(void) {
    struct y {
  }; a, b, c, d;
    struct x {
  } a, b, c, d;
}
```

Two different statements, two completely different meanings, both legal C / C++, and the only difference is the `;` after the struct declaration.

Comment: What does the comma do, in "a,b,c,d" at the end of struct y?

Comment: While the second series obviously defines 4 `struct x` objects, the first series actually defines a bunch of `int` variables.

Comment: What are the different meanings?

Answer (score 9):

Because the next word following the `}` may declare a variable of said type.  This is a relic from C:

```
struct S { int a; } s;
s.a;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is legal in C++:

```
struct MyStruct
{
} anInstanceOfMyStruct;

struct
{
} anInstanceOfAnUnnamedStruct;
```

You need the semicolon to indicate you aren't creating a new instance.  The language designers of C# and Java apparently didn't feel that allowing this was a useful addition to their language.