# Why mustn't I put a semicolon at the end of class declaration in C#

Tags: c#

In a C# class declaration:

```
class thing
{
    ...
}
```

Why, at the end of class declaration, must I not include the semicolon? It's really different from C++. You can see [Why must I put a semicolon at the end of a class declaration in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783465/why-must-i-put-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-class-declaration-in-c)

Comment: Because nothing expected to be specified after latest `}`?

Comment: @viperchaos I think the answers in the linked question contains all the answers you need -- just reverse them ;-)

Comment: Really, didnt your link already provide the answer? Its used in C++ for historical reasons since you can define an instance after declaring the class which isnt possible in C#. why not put a semicolon after a namespace, method, property etc??

Comment: @Polity your mind is really sharp!!

Comment: You only include the comma after the closing bracket in the class **declaration** (which you'd usually find in a header file in C++). **In C#, the declaration and definition are not separated** (and there are no separate header files), so no semicolon is required. There's no difference in the syntax between a C# definition and a C++ definition.

Comment: Why did this question get closed? It's a valid question.

Comment: @Pino: No, it's not. The only valid answer is "because the spec says you don't". That's not really what I call a valid question.

Comment: @Cody It has an answer. So it's a valid question, it's not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and it certainly can be reasonably answered in its current form, as you have proved above.

Comment: @Pino: I think it counts as both "vague" and "rhetorical". I also don't think "because the spec says so" is a "reasonable answer", so I disagree that it can "be reasonably answered in its current form". Also, don't let the subtext fool you: questions get closed as "not a real question" because they're simply **bad** questions that shouldn't have been asked in the first place. This one is a good example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that is [what the language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e&displaylang=en) says.

Remember that C# wasn't designed with any C++ compatibility in mind. The language designers has simply decided, that the ending semi-colon is not needed.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I don't think you can say that C# as a language is compatible with C++ in any way. They look somewhat like each other, and both use braces-and-semicolons like a lot of other languages, but that is all.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (page 263) says it is optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you use semicolon after block declarations, your application will still compile fine but you'll get a warning that you have an extra semicolon. C# does not expect blocks to be terminated with semicolon by default.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Arbitrary block
        {
        }; // Semicolon here is fine but not required
    }
}; // Semicolon here is also fine but not required
```

Comment: The innermost semicolon adds an **empty statement** to the code of `MyMethod`. If the code is compiled without optimizations, for example in `Debug` configuration/mode, the empty statement could become an (additional) CIL instruction `nop` ("no operation"). When compiled in `Release`, the empty statement is most certainly ignored. On the other hand, the outermost semicolon (which was what the asker meant) does not change anything, so it is purely a matter of what style you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN put the semicolon at the end of a class declaration if you want, but it's not required. It's optional by design, probably to maintain style compatibility with C++.