# C++ Method declaration using another class

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm starting to learn C++ (coming from Java), so bear with me.

I can't seem to get my method declaration to accept a class I've made.

> 'Context' has not been declared

I think I'm not understanding a fundamental concept, but I don't know what.

Expression.h

```
#include "Context.h"  
class Expression {  
public:  
    void interpret(Context *);  // This line has the error
    Expression();  
    virtual ~Expression();  
};
```

Context.h

```
#include <stack>  
#include <vector>  
#include "Expression.h"  

class Context {  
private:  
    std::stack<Expression*,std::vector<Expression*> > theStack;  
public:  
    Context();  
    virtual ~Context();  
};
```

Comment: Youve kinda got a circular definition going on!  Context uses expression, and expression uses Context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783465/why-must-i-put-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-class-declaration-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to forward declare `Expression` in `Context` or vice versa (or both), otherwise you have a cyclic dependency. For example,

Expression.h:

```
class Context; // no include, we only have Context*.

class Expression {  
public:  
    void interpret(Context *);  // This line has the error
    Expression();  
    virtual ~Expression();  
};
```

Context.h:

```
#include <stack>  
#include <vector>  

class Expression; // No include, we only have Expression*

class Context {  
private:  
    std::stack<Expression*,std::vector<Expression*> > theStack;  
public:  
    Context();  
    virtual ~Context();  
};
```

You can perform the forward declarations because the full definition of the classes isn't needed, since you are only referring to pointers to the other class in each case. It is likely that you will need the includes in the implementation files (that is, `#include "Context.h"` in `Expression.cpp` and `#include Expression.h` in `Context.cpp`).

Finally, remember to put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files.

Comment: My bad, I simply forgot to add them. They are actually are there in my code.

Comment: @spudfkc OK, the important point is the cyclic include dependencies, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, class definitions always have to end with a semi-colon `;`
so example:

```
class foo {};
```

Java and C# doesn't require that, so I can see your confusion.

Also it looks like both your header files include each other. Thus it's kind of like a snake eating it's tail: Where does it start? Thus in your Expression.h you can replace the 'include' with a forward declaration instead:

```
class Context;
class Expression {  
public:  
    void interpret(Context *);  // This line has the error
    Expression();  
    virtual ~Expression();  
}
```

And last but not least, you should put a compiler guard to prevent the header from getting included more than once into a .cpp file. You can put a `#pragma once` in the top of the header file. That is useful if you are using visual studio and the microsoft compiler. I don't know if GCC supports it or not. Or you can wrap your header file like this:

```
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H_
#define EXPRESSION_H_
    class Context;
    class Expression {  
    public:  
        void interpret(Context *);  // This line has the error
        Expression();  
        virtual ~Expression();  
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Don't use names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_EXPRESSION_H`) or names that contain two consecutive underscores. They are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to forward declare the classes Context and Expression in the header files before the #include

e.g.

```
    #include <stack>  
    #include <vector>  

// forward declaration   
class Context;
    class Expression;

    #include "Expression.h"  

    class Context {  
    private:  
        std::stack<Expression*,std::vector<Expression*> > theStack;  
    public:  
        Context();  
        virtual ~Context();  
    }
```